# MVC request to Web Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to build an MVC that requests through a PCL to a WebApi. I am sending a get requests and getting stuck on the awaiting for the response. Postman returns the correct values. I also don t get exceptions on send. The 3 projects are both on the same solution.

**PCL**

```
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = null;
        try
        {
             httpResponse = await _http.GetAsync( "http://localhost:43818/api/values" );

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var meessage = e.Message;
            var stack = e.StackTrace;

        }

        if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            string json = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync( );
        }
```

So the issue is that in the PCL, it's doesn pass the await, it gets stuck.

**MVC**

```
       var result = apiClient.GetIndex( );
```

**Web Api**

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

Also, how do i wait in my MVC for the response before rendering the controller view

Comment: What is your definition of PCL?

Comment: @ErikPhilips Portable Class Library, i m sorry for not mentioning

Comment: Can you paste signature of your PCL and all its methods ?

Comment: I see an `await`.  It's really important when posting async code to post the *entire* chain of code using async/await.

Comment: The _apiClient.GetIndex( );_ is actually the PCL function with a return

Comment: If GetIndex is async, you need to await it in MVC, and make the MVC controller action async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i found the best sollution. Blocking threads is not a very good idea.

This is the fix

**PCL**

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Register()
{
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
    {
        RequestUri = new Uri( _http.BaseAddress, "account/register/" ),
        Method = HttpMethod.Post,
        Content = new StringContent( "{\"Email\": \"email@yahoo.com\",\"Password\": \"Password!1\",\"ConfirmPassword\": \"Password!1\"}",
        Encoding.UTF8,
        _contentType
        ),
    };


        HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

        try
        {
            response = await _http.SendAsync( request, CancellationToken.None );
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Debugger.Break();
        }

    return response;
}
```

**MVC Client**

```
    public async Task<ViewResult> Index( )
    {
        var thisTask = await Api.Register( );

        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In your **Class library (PCL)**, Create method GetIndex as below,

```
    public async Task GetIndexAsync()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage httpResponse = null;
        try
        {
            _http.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:43818/");
            httpResponse = await _http.GetAsync("api/values");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var meessage = e.Message;
            var stack = e.StackTrace;

        }

        if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            string json = await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
```

And In **MVC** calling method as below,

```
var result = apiClient.GetIndexAsync().Wait();
```

which solved both your problems.

Comment: it worked, just that you can't store the result in var, a task type must be set and from there you can fetch the result. Thank you for your answer!